# Why can't I put a condition in update statement?

Tags: kdb

I have a table:

`t:([]val:10?100)`

And I want to add a column with a cond statement: If value is below 55, just set it  to 55. However the update statement does not work with that:

`update newVal:$[val<55;55;val] from`

How do I have to change it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since val is a vector you have to use the vector conditional

```
update newVal:?[val<55;55;val] from t
```

By the way, an alternative way of flooring it out at 55 is to use max/or (|)

```
update val|55 from t
```

Answer (score 0):

I think @terrylynch is perfect. But sometimes when vector condition is too hard to use, you can use a lambda inside q-sql statement as well. And for the reason for using vector condition is simply because a column is a list

```
q)t
val
---
12
10
1
90
73
90
43
90
84
63
q)update newVal:{$[x<55;55;x]}each val from t
val newVal
----------
12  55
10  55
1   55
90  90
73  73
90  90
43  55
90  90
84  84
63  63                          
q)update newVal:{x|55}each val from t
val newVal
----------
12  55
10  55
1   55
90  90
73  73
90  90
43  55
90  90
84  84
63  63
```

Comment: Worth mentioning that 'lambda each' introduces a performance hit, especially for larger tables.